# How can I add certain number of day to a date, with python - timedelta?

Tags: python, django

I am stuck with an issue. Basically, I have to add, depending on the type of duration, a certain number of days to a date. My model and functions are like that:

```
models.py

from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.
 
FRAZIONAMENTO = (
    ('Annuale', 'Annuale'),
    ('Semestrale', 'Semestrale'),
    ('Quadrimestrale', 'Quadrimestrale'),
    ('Mensile', 'Mensile'),
)


 

class Polizza(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numero_polizza = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data_decorrenza = models.DateField()
    data_scadenza = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ramo_polizza = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=RAMO_POLIZZA)
    polizza_nuova = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    frazionamento = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=FRAZIONAMENTO)
    premio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    provvigione = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    creata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    aggiornata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Polizza'
        ordering = ['data_scadenza']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ramo_polizza + ' ' + self.frazionamento



    @property
    def get_data_scadenza(self):
        if self.frazionamento == 'Annuale':
            data_scadenza = self.data_decorrenza + \
                str(datetime.timedelta(days=365))
        elif self.frazionamento == 'Semestrale':
            data_scadenza = self.data_decorrenza + \
                str(datetime.timedelta(days=180))
        elif self.frazionamento == 'Quadrimestrale':
            data_scadenza = self.data_decorrenza + \
                str(datetime.timedelta(days=120))
        elif self.frazionamento == 'Mensile':
            data_scadenza = self.data_decorrenza + \
                str(datetime.timedelta(days=30))    

        return data_scadenza

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.provvigione = self.get_provvigione
        super(Polizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
 def nuova_polizza(request):
    clienti = Cliente.objects.all()
    polizze = Polizza.objects.all()
    context = {
        'clienti': clienti,
        'polizze': polizze,
    }
    return render(request, 'anagrafica/nuova_polizza.html', context)

def salva_nuova_polizza(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cliente = request.POST.get('cliente')
        numero_polizza = request.POST.get('numero_polizza')
        data_decorrenza = request.POST.get('data_decorrenza')
        ramo_polizza = request.POST.get('ramo_polizza')
        frazionamento = request.POST.get('frazionamento')
        premio = int(request.POST.get('premio'))

        polizza = Polizza(cliente_id=cliente, numero_polizza=numero_polizza, data_decorrenza=data_decorrenza,
                          ramo_polizza=ramo_polizza, frazionamento=frazionamento, premio=premio)
        polizza.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('anagrafica:lista_clienti'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Metodo non Consentito')
```

It's returning me this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“2022-01-01120 days, 0:00:00” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

I know that probably is some just tiny mistake but I couldn't find it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does returning a sliced string help? Something like: `return str(data_scadenza)[:10]`

Comment: No, actually it doesn't give me any other error. I probably have to assign some kind of variable and probably specify with strptime or strftime, but I am not able to find the proper syntax

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error message you are concattinating strings:

```
data_scadenza = self.data_decorrenza + \
                str(datetime.timedelta(days=30))
```

Try this:

```
data_scadenza = self.data_decorrenza + \
                datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the end, which is:
models.py

```
@property
def get_data_scadenza(self):
    data_decorrenza = dt.strptime(self.data_decorrenza, '%Y-%m-%d')
    if self.frazionamento == 'Annuale':
        data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=365)
    elif self.frazionamento == 'Semestrale':
        data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=180)
    elif self.frazionamento == 'Quadrimestrale':
        data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=120)
    elif self.frazionamento == 'Mensile':
        data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=30)

    return data_scadenza
```

Now everything works perfectly!!